# Transaction execution error of EVM "EvmCoreErrorExitReason (OutOfFund)"

Tags: evm, substrate-node, frontend

I have developed Substrate Network with `EVM compatibility` and `POA consensus algorithm`.
It was working fine and transaction execution time was although alot but for now getting an error from `EVM-core`.
I have tried to deploy smart contract and it failed. Then i tried to execute light weight transactions as like sending ethers from wallet 1 to wallet 2 but still it was throwing error of

> **EvmCoreErrorExitReason (OutOfFund)**

on `PolkaDot Explorer`. Let me know how i can enhance the execution time of transactions and how i can Fix this error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this by myself.
The Error was because of MetaMask wallet. Sometimes the transaction fails and the nonce of MetaMask wallet increases but the chain expects the previous nonce.

After reseting the MetaMask Account and Nonce to 0, I Initialised transactions and every transaction was executing smoothly.